# Problem with VLOOKUP Function when key search is an URL

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I need to applay a Vlookup function , to view ID foreach url:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vntqY3yJA56dOUVHwrsyeHHamCQD0IiKGLy-a6kVkeM/edit?usp=sharing

it doesn't work!! it seems like Vlookup dont execute when the key search is an URl, Anyone have an idea ??!
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's not how `VLOOKUP()` works. It will search the value in the 1st column of the given range, then it can return a value from any of the columns to the **right** of that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell `Match!A2` (deleting everything below):

```
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(B2:B;{List!B:B\List!A:A};2;0);))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the match function is better than Vlookup in this case! it's working now